# Is there a way to get incomplete Guerrilla Actions back after a sector has been liberated in Red Faction: Guerrilla?

Tags: achievements, red-faction-guerrilla

While playing Red Faction: Guerrilla I noticed that once you liberate a sector, all the incomplete Guerilla Actions apart from the Transporter and Demolition ones disappear.

If I wanted to get the Revolutionary achievement (Complete all Guerrilla Actions), is there a way to do this without starting a new game and methodically completing all actions in a sector before liberating it?

Comment: Needs a new red-faction-guerrilla tag (I don't have enough rep to add it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently playing *Red Faction: Guerilla* by chance. This thread suggests that the guerilla actions will spawn (i.e. you get the radio message telling you what to do) when you are in roughly the right area. The list might help find the ones you are missing.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/944786-red-faction-guerrilla/50007286

It certainly seems you can go back and mop them all up after completing the main story:

> **"Missions will respawn if you missed
>   them"**
>
> *demiface*

Comment: Ah, so you get a chance to complete them once you finish the story. Thanks! That list looks like it will be handy too.